# Akeidah and Ketoret

Tags: history, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer, provenance, korbanos-ketores-prayers

The earliest siddur I own (London, 5569 [18808-09]) does not include Ketoret or Akeidah, despite purporting to follow the customs of the "German and **Polish**" communities [emphasis mine]. Since most of the eastern Ashkenazi siddurim I've seen have both of these portions, as well as gemara excerpts before Zevachim 5, I have wondered when they were added. Is there any documentation, such as old siddurim or writings of Acharonim, which points to an origin of the usage of these passages in birchot hashachar?

Comment: rabbeinu saa3dyo jo'ons siddur zl doesnt have it not does rabbeinu 3amrom jo'ons zl siddur not does nor does shalomo ban rabbi nothons zl siddur. all 3 are the earliest siddurs. http://genizah.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/profile/manuscript/87ea9632-0695-4f46-9841-524aa5f36191 this siddur is from the cairo janizo and it is pretty old, early rishonim time period. it most likely doesnt have it as well, but i didnt look through it. original tiklaleem of yaman didnt have it as well for they want according to rambama zl and he didnt mention it either

Comment: the origins of these being added are kabalistic. about 1500s.

Comment: This explains why the Germans do not include it to this day.

Comment: or they dont want to keep on adding to the siddur to where it becomes like an encyclopedia sized book. when in reality if you see the link above, the entire book is all the barochoth and piyyu6eem for weekday shabboth and yomeem 6oveem. thats how it originally was. it was a book intended to have all the things needed to be said in one book. short and to the point as intended by 7azal. however, as people kept on adding piyyu6eem(especially ashkanazim) to holiday and shabboth services, the original siddur was broken into other siddurim and ma7zorim

Comment: There is an antiquarian siddur in the family entitled "Tikkun Shabbat" which has all of the piyutim in an appendix in the back. Much like the Conservative siddurim, it only lacks tefillot for weekday shacharit and Yomim Noraim. On the other hand, in Washington Heights, they at least used to use Heidenheim's Dvar Yom B'Yomo on special shabbatot, which also includes hoshanot (it's somewhat lighter than a translated sidddur) and selichot (of which we have fewer than the Sepharadim). It also includes the special variations on Kedushah to be added after "Ani Hashem Eloheichem".

Comment: thats the problem with ashkanazim siddurim. they added piyyu6eem to their prayers when it was not needed. and rabbeinu tam tried to reconcile it with some mishnayyoth and he makes a fool of himself. ashkanazi rishonim are famous for trying to reconcile ashkanazi shtetl customs which had nothing to do with judaism and/or didnt make sense wit the halochoth of the jamoro wa mishno in order to appease the public. http://moreshetsepharad.org/media/-The_Legal_Thinking_of_the_Tosafot_A_Historical_Approach_by_Jose_Faur.pdf

Comment: Do Teimanim have no piyutim added at all? Even the Amoraic and Geonic ones such as El Adon?

Comment: they do have eil adon, the rambam zl brings if in the back of seifar ahabo. They don't have qabboloth shabboth, they start at borachu(now a days they added on all the common things for no reason other than being 3ammai 3aro9eem)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16714/discussion-between-noach-mi-frankfurt-and-moridoweedhyaa3qob).